# Get the real serial number of Hard-Disk in computer using java

Tags: java, hard-drive, serial-number

I've been trying this code, but I wonder the output is not the serial number (SN). The result only contains the number without alphabet. I wonder, it must be the combination between number and alphabet.

Here is the code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class DiskUtils {
    private DiskUtils() {  }

    public static String getSerialNumber(String drive) {
        String result = "";
        try {
            File file = File.createTempFile("realhowto",".vbs");
            file.deleteOnExit();
            FileWriter fw = new java.io.FileWriter(file);

            String vbs = "Set objFSO = CreateObject(\"Scripting.FileSystemObject\")\n"
                        +"Set colDrives = objFSO.Drives\n"
                        +"Set objDrive = colDrives.item(\"" + drive + "\")\n"
                        +"Wscript.Echo objDrive.SerialNumber";  // see note
            fw.write(vbs);
            fw.close();
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript //NoLogo " + file.getPath());
            BufferedReader input =
              new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
               result += line;
            }
            input.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result.trim();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
      String sn = DiskUtils.getSerialNumber("C");
      javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog((java.awt.Component)
           null, sn, "Serial Number of C:",
           javax.swing.JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
    }
}
```

Then, i also have tried to proof the real SN that may be true (contains number and alphabet).
Here is the tutorial that I got to check the real SN of hard-disk :

1. Open up a command prompt window (Start Menu > All Programs > Accessories > Command Prompt).
2. Type in: vol.
3. The Volume Serial Number is the Disk Serial Number.

The result between the code and the tutorial has really a big different. 
Do you guys know, which one is true ? And how to proof that ?

Comment: This appears to be a Windows Power Shell specific approach (and that may be sufficient for your needs), what type of output are you getting? Why not execute and parse the results of the `vol` command directly?

Comment: I wanna know the right code of JAVA how to get SN of Hard-disk on computer.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something more along the lines of this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class SerialNumber
{
  public String executeVolCommand()
  {
    String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    try{

      Process pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c", "vol").start();  
      InputStream in = pb.getInputStream();  
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));  
      String line;  
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
        buffer.append(line + NEWLINE);  
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    return buffer.toString();      }
}
```

Then, once you have the result, you can parse it for the actual serial number.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it's really helpful. But, i'm still wondering which one is the right SN of Hard-Disk ?

Comment: Since you don't post the contents of your script file we can't deduce what it is doing. In addition, the serial number you see created by the vol command is software generated by the OS when the drive is initially formatted.  It isn't the actual manufacturers serial number.  Check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_serial_number  Other posts I've read explain this.  I don't think there really is a definitive way to obtain the manufacturers serial number.  That might require further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want the answer...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SerialNumber {

public static void main ( String[] args ) throws Exception {

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec ( "ioreg -l" );
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        while ( ( i = is.read() ) != -1 ) if ( ( char ) i != '|' && ( char ) i != ' ' ) sb.append ( ( char ) i );
        InputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream ( sb.toString().getBytes() );
        Properties pro = new Properties();
        pro.load ( fis );
        System.out.println ( pro.get ( "\"IOPlatformSerialNumber\"" ).toString().substring ( 1, pro.get ( "\"IOPlatformSerialNumber\"" ).toString().length() - 1 ) );

    }

}
```

I am running **Mac OSX 10.10**

Comment: Because this is Java and the preceding answer was written for Windows, and this is written for MAC, it's really not very helpful.

Comment: @Will getting the info for a Mac is useful, if one needs something that will work on all platforms, you need code for each supported platform.

Comment: Because the OP is clearly running Windows, it's really not at all helpful to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // InputStream stream = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic diskdrive get name,size,model,SerialNumber ").getInputStream();
    List<String> collect;
    InputStream stream = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic diskdrive get SerialNumber ").getInputStream();

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream))) {

     collect  = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
        /*while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        model += line;
        }*/
    }
```

Note: The BufferedReader class gives you several ways to get infos from inputstream